# Django fix existing database according to migrations

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, django-database

I inherited a django (1.11.6, database PostgreSQL) project and I am new with it. Recently I noticed that some tables differ from the ones generated by `manage.py sqlmigrate` for instance, `manage.py inspectdb` returns

```
class TheClass(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ...
```

and migrations have:

```
migrations.CreateModel(
            name='TheClass',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ...
```

In addition, they have different constraint names ans so on, column names are correct. I think this is the result of incorrect transfer. And I want to fix the table in accordance with migrations leaving the data untouched. I tried using `sqldiff`, but it returned no differences and I didn't manage to find the answer.

Comment: Do you have a lot of incoherences? If not, just change slightly the fields you want to correct, run `makemigrations` then `migrate` so Django can detect the differences, then go back to the original wished values, again with `makemigrations` and `migrate`. Hopefully that could correct the little incoherences!

Comment: @KrazyMax, thank you! Well, the change that truly concerns me - is that `id` is not serial, so I will have to add AutoField to Model. Other issues are wrong constraint names, etc. It would be great to know the robust way to fix this. But for now, I think I can try the way you suggested.